# should a multiline var f = function() { /* Code */ } get a semicolon

Tags: javascript, coding-style

When setting a variable to reference a function in a multi-line declaration, should it be followed by a semicolon. Take the folling for example:

```
function sayHi(name) {
    (window.console && console.log || alert)('Hello ' + name);
}

var sayBye = function(name) {
    (window.console && console.log || alert)('Cya ' + name);
};
```

Should there be a semicolon after the second declaration as it fits with a var keyword, on the other hand, function definitions don't usually have a semicolon at the end.

Comment: Yes, the ECMA spec requires it for expressions -- including function expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first function is a *function declaration*, not a statement.
It does not need a semicolon.

The second function is a regular statement that happens to involve a function *expression*.
Like all other statements, it should end with an optional semicolon.

Comment: Noted.  I created my own answer anyway, just for shucks and grins.  +1 for being correct.

Answer (score 0):

It does not *need* a semicolon thanks to JavaScript parser magic, but Douglas Crockford would have a hernia if you didn't use one.  In other words, it's considered good coding style to use a semicolon after assigning an anonymous function to a variable.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks! 200 a day really isn't *too* hard if you put your mind to it. Though I have forgotten what it's like outside... hmm...

Comment: Yes; I know.  (although you haven't actually been here 50 days)

Comment: @SLaks: Yup, answered questions and one bounty helped a bit there. :)  I seem to average about 223/day.  I think I hear my life crying out in terror.