# Do we need a semicolon after function declaration?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: When should I use a semicolon after curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717949/javascript-when-should-i-use-a-semicolon-after-curly-braces)

Someone added semicolon after function declaration, but someone not. Is this a good practice to add semicolon after function declaration?

```
function test(o) {
}

function test(o) {
};
```

Comment: This might be relevant: [should a multiline var f = function() { /* Code */ } get a semicolon](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4515084/990877). To summarize: close with a `;` when declaring the function in an assignment expression (i.e. `var f = function() {}`).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) does not need (and should not have) a semicolon following it:

```
function test(o) {
}
```

However, if you write a function as an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Syntax), like the variable initializer below, then the statement should be terminated with a semicolon, just like any other statement would be:

```
var a = function test(o) {
};
```

See more about [constructor vs declaration(statement) vs expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Constructor_vs._declaration_vs._expression).

Comment: Why does a function declaration not need a semicolon? It seems weird that variable declarations and variable calls use semicolons but only function calls and not function declarations do.

Answer (score 5):

What's actually happening there is you're adding an empty statement after the function.

```
function test (o) { return o; };
```

could be seen as being similar to:

```
var test = 0;;
```

That second semicolon isn't an ***error*** per-se.  The browser treats it like a statement where absolutely nothing happened.

There are two things to keep in mind, here.

This applies ***ONLY*** to function-declarations and control-blocks (for/if/while/switch/etc).

Function-declarations should be defined at the bottom of your scope, so you don't run into problems like this:

```
function test () {}
(function (window, document, undefined) { /* do stuff */ }(window, document));
```

Because the browser will assume that you mean `function test() {}(/*return value of closure*/);`
Which is an error.  A very bad and nasty error which is very easy to overlook.

But that's okay, because function-declarations can go under return statements and still work just fine.

So even if you wanted to go:

```
function doStuff () {
    return (function () { /*process stuff*/ test(); }());
    function test () {}
}
```

That's going to work just peachy.

Answer (score 4):

Semicolons and function declarations:

```
function test(o) {
    // body
} // semicolon no

var test = function (o) {
    // body
}; // semicolon yes
```

See [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) for formatting code questions.

Comment: Semicolon is not required in the second type of function declaration as well. The code after it runs without any problems.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You don't need semicolons when defining a function like that.

However, if you define a function like this:

```
var test = function (o) {
}
```

It's not strictly necessary, but you may want to use them, especially if you put the function on one line.

The first way defines a function, but the second way assigns a function to a variable, and thus is a statement. Most statements are semicolon delimited. Defining functions could be considered a common counterexample, as not many people do use them.

Answer (score 1):

To the browser, it doesn't matter. For matter of semantics, it only matters if you're prototyping a function or using the function statement.

```
function stuff(stuff) {
     alert(stuff);
} //don't need a semicolon

Object.prototype.stuff = function(stuff) {
    alert(stuff);
}; //need a semicolon
var stuff = function(stuff) {
    alert(stuff);
}; //need a semicolon
```

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon is not required while defining a function, but putting it on is not a mistake either.

One exception though, if you use function wrappers and pass the parameters, you **need** to add semicolons in between, example:

```
(function(v){alert(v)})('1');
(function(s){alert(s)})('0')
```

- or it will result in error: http://jsfiddle.net/twUD3/1/

`... Otherwise forget about them ...`